# Changing the table-name of AspNetUsers in ASP.NET Identity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I have 2 questions... I am using the Identity Framework and the Entity Framework for storing user data.

The default name of the User-Table is "AspNetUsers". Normally I use data annotations to change the table name to "Users" with:

```
[Table("Users")]
```

But this does not work here. Instead, I have to use the fluent API to achieve my goal:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
```

This works perfectly fine, but it's not the preferred way since I want to have my code consistent and renaming tables works fine with other data-classes with data annotations.

2) When I have changed the table-name via fluent-API I got another problem. The UserManager of the Identity-Framework can't find the table anymore. Is the table name hard-wired in the code? Can't believe that!?

Every time I am using the UserManager, for example, to create a new user, I get an exception that the table "AspNetUsers" can't be found. How can I fix that?

Comment: In your `Users` table have you got all the columns as to what they were in `AspNetUsers`?

Comment: Annotation should be `[Table("Users")]`. Also note that fluent trumps annotations.

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake. Of course [Table("Users")]. I corrected this in my post.